# Is there any performance impact of calling ToList() multiple times?

Tags: c#, linq

I started working on a project and I have noticed that ToList() gets called multiple times and I think it is not really necessary and redundant.

The first ToList() is at the data layer where the call goes to database and gets the data.

```
    public IEnumerable<Company> GetCompanies()
    {
        return DbContext.Companies.ToList();
    }
```

Then at the controller I can see another call as ToList()

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var companies = _companyService.GetCompanies().ToList();
        return View(companies);
    }
```

I believe that calling ToList() in the controller is redundant. But I just wonder whether it has any impact on performance or the language itself recognizes automatically that the result is actually is already list and ignores the second call?

> Update

The other question asks if there is an impact calling ToList(). However, I wonder whether there is an impact calling the ToList() multiple times for the same list of objects. As someone mentioned that that should be "hopefully ignored".

Comment: It is poor design. Your methods should return as specific type as possible in the signature. The method arguments should be as generic as possible. In the above case the signature of `GetCompanies` should be changed to return `List<Company>`

Comment: Use a profiler to check *if* a call has any impact. We can´t know as we don´t know where your data comes from. Is it a database? Some service? A file? This has a high influence on wheather the results will be cached or not. But most important is: what is `DbContext.Companies`?

Comment: Hopefully the redundant call is ignored since `ToList()` on a list won't make sense

Comment: @Rahul, `ToList()` on an `List<T>` **does** perfectly make sense, since this is not casting and not a type conversion method. This method creates a `List<T>` using the provided `IEnumerable<T>` as items source.

Comment: @Igor "Your methods should return as specific type as possible in the signature." I don´t agree, a method should return what the caller may need. There´s no need to force a method to return a list, if we only want to iterate the result. However if we want to add some data to the result you surely want a list.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - I am not stating that all methods should return a List but if a method returns Type `C` and `C` derives from `B` and `B` from `A` then the return type of the method should be declared as `C` and not `B` or `A`. There are exceptions, like when abstracting return types (returning interfaces instead of concrete types in the signature) but when dealing with standard built in .net types (`List<T>` included) this is *almost* always preferred.

Comment: not sure why this is marked as duplicated? @PatrickHofman. The other question is just asking whether there is performance impact calling the ToList(). I wonder whether there is an impact calling it multiple times.

Comment: And I am confused with the answers given here.

Comment: Which is the same. Impact once is impact multiple times.

Comment: *This constructor must make a copy of the array (more generally IEnumerable<T>), otherwise future modifications of the original array will change on the source T[] also which wouldn't be desirable generally.*

Comment: @akd well is there is perfomance impact calling it once - there is more perfomance impact calling it multiple times, not?

Comment: @Evk just thinking that the language might just ignore the second call as it is redundant. Similar the SQL query optimizer that analyse your  query.

Comment: @akd yes but the accepted answer in duplicated question provides details of `ToList` implementation where you can see that even if you call `ToList` on `List<T>` - it will still copy it to the new list.

Comment: @HimBromBeere it is database. retrieving data from database.

Comment: @Evk thanks I missed that bit.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a performance impact. Even if the underlying `IEnumerable<T>` is already a `List<T>` a call to `ToList` will cause  new list to be created (so `list != list.ToList()`). Depending on the size of the original list, this may have serious performance implications